# Attach Database SQLCIPHER

Tags: android, sqlcipher

I want to know this code is necessary to use in SQLcipher.(using in android)

I am confused where and when should i use this if needed.

i want to encrypt my sqlite db.

```
ATTACH DATABASE 'encrypted.db' AS encrypted KEY 'secret'; -- create a new encrypted database
CREATE TABLE encrypted.t1(a,b); -- recreate the schema in the new database (you can inspect all objects using SELECT * FROM sqlite_master)
INSERT INTO encrypted.t1 SELECT * FROM t1; -- copy data from the existing tables to the new tables in the encrypted database
DETACH DATABASE encrypted;
```

Answer (score 1):

The sample code you have posted below allows you to attach a database and replicates a single table into from an existing database.  If you intend on replicating the schema and content from one database to another, it is recommended to use the convenience function `sqlcipher_export`.  You can read more about it with examples [here](http://sqlcipher.net/sqlcipher-api/#sqlcipher_export).